# iOS7: UILabel Text in Custom Cell does not appear without GCD

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

Text in the Label of a Custom Cell appears with a block.   Is there a better way to accomplish this?

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *circle;
@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@implementation CustomCell
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.circle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40.0f, 40.0f)];
    [self.circle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor];

    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 20, 200.0f, 50.0f)];
    self.label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self.contentView addSubview:self.label];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.circle];

//I have also tried [self addSubview:self.label];

}
```

tableView.m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *customCellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:inviteCellIdentifier];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[cell label] setText:@"This is Label"];
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
});
    return cell;
}
```

The only way I can get the UILabel to display text is by using the Block above.  If I don't use the block and simply use `cell.Label.text = @"This is a Label"` followed by `[cell setNeedsDisplay];`, the text does not appear and I have to scroll the tableview causing the cells to reload, and only then the text in the label finally appears.

Is there better way or am I stuck with having to use the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't create the `UILabel` for the `label` property until the cell's `layoutSubviews` method is called which is long after you attempt to set the label's text in your table view controller.

Move the creation of the labels to the custom cell's `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method. Also put the call to `self.contentView addSubview:` in the `init...` method. The only thing that should be in the `layoutSubviews` method is the setting of the label's frame.

Once you do that you won't need the use of GCD in the `cellForRow...` method.

Do the same for the `circle` property too.

BTW - your use of GCD solves the issue because it gives the cell a change for its `layoutSubviews` method to be called, creating the label.

Comment: do I initialize and set the frame in layoutsubviews?  or initialize in the iniwithstyle and set the frame in layoutsubviews?

Comment: In the `init...` method you call `self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:...];` and `[self.contentView addSubview:self.label]` as well as setting other label properties. `layoutSubviews` only needs to adjust the frame as needed.

Comment: And do the same for the `circle` property too.

Comment: So I moved everything from layout subviews to init and it worked.  I swear I tired that earlier and it didn't!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not be allocating and placing views in layoutSubviews. The views should be created and placed when the cell is created and you only alter the frames (if required) in the layoutSubviews method. Otherwise you're going to get a tonne of duplicate views on top of each other.

Next, you should not be using dispatch_async inside of tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. You can just set the text label directly. Nor should you need setNeedsDisplay since the system will do that anyway with the new cell.